# how to find value in table excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

It's exist formula in excel if i want found id, by value? Example

```
Id;values
1;a
2;b
3;c
```

Findinarray(value,colums check, colums return value

Findinarray("b";B2:B4;A2:A4)
//Return 2

Comment: In Excel, this is called **VLOOKUP()** or **MATCH()** and **INDEX()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Lookup(). I have noticed and so have others that Lookup() isn't always the most precise method weirdly. So the best way is to use Match() with a combination of other formula methods, e.g. Indirect(), Row(), Cell() (to name a few)